# Does Android Gmail used C2DM?

Tags: android, notifications, gmail, push

Does Gmail, Contacts and Calendar uses C2DM to do push? 
The above is not open source app, but some one may know the answer.

Comment: Yeah I heard that this is true, but I can't find the youtube video where I saw this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is no. Gmail doesn't use C2DM. To identify if an app uses C2DM it should have the permission like below inside AndroidManifest.xml.

```
<!-- Cloud to Device Messaging permissions -->
<permission
    android:name="com.example.jumpnote.android.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
    android:protectionLevel="signature" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.example.jumpnote.android.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />
```

Note: the above permission when you look in the market it should be equivalent below:

```
NETWORK COMMUNICATION
RECEIVE DATA FROM INTERNET
Allows the applications to accept cloud to device messages sent by the application's service. Using this service will incur data usage. Malicious applications may cause excess data usage.
```

Then see the Gmail app in the Market, it does not use such permission.

Answer (score 0):

Yes they do :

"Many of the Google applications on Android already use push to keep their data fresh, for example Gmail, Contacts, and Calendar. Starting with Android 2.2, C2DM allows third-party developers to use the same service the Google apps do."

Source : http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2010/05/android-cloud-to-device-messaging.html

Comment: Thanks Ravi! yeah, I have seen that one and try its sample app called jumpnote. When I run the jumpnote it sync the data gracefully. In the phone>application management>running app>google service> google cloud service is running. But when only Gmail is in sync, I don't see that "google cloud service". So I am thinking that google uses different push.